# using same thread variable in different functions

Tags: java, android, multithreading, printing

I have a Java lib for a specific printer and to write to the printer I need to run it in a thread, but I have different function in my printer class, one that align text one that print a barcode, etc...
To be able to print I have to get the port to the printer and use this port for the different functions.
Here is the code:

```
port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName,PortSettings, 10000,null);
```

In the diffrent functions I would use the port like this:

```
try {
StarPrinterStatus status = null;
status = port.beginCheckedBlock();
port.writePort(Text,0,Text.length);
status = port.endCheckedBlock();
catch (StarIOPortException e)
    {
}
```

and when finish the print job.

```
if(port != null){
try {
     StarIOPort.releasePort(port);
} catch (StarIOPortException e) {}
}
```

How can I create a thread and use the same "port" in all functions?

Comment: You're going to want to read up on concurrent programming in general; this is a very, very broad subject. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks but it didn't tell me anything that I din't already know. What I need is a way to get like a handle to the variable post so I can use it over and over again in the same thread.

Comment: Store it in member field or subclass Runnable into a custom class that lets you take the port object in through the constructor.